# Ubuntu set password for mysql_secure_installation

Tags: javascript, php, linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to execute command that will change root password and configure mysql_secure_installation in one line.
I had success with Centos 8 and it worked like that:

```
printf "y\n 6esx9thv-!7DATABASE\n 6adsx9tpa-!7DATSE\n y\n y\n" | mysql_secure_installation
```

I tried same command for Linux but it's not working, and here I am with this command:

```
sudo mysql -e "SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD(`6adsx9tpa-!7DATSE`);FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" &&
sudo mysql -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=``;" && 
sudo mysql -e "DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User=`root` AND Host NOT IN (`localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `::1`);" && 
sudo mysql -e "DROP DATABASE test;DELETE FROM mysql.db WHERE Db=`test` OR Db=`gmanager_%`;" && 
sudo mysql -u root -psomething -e "CREATE USER `ubuntu`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY `6adsx9tpa-!7DATSE`;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `ubuntu`@`localhost`;FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

And when I try that I have error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD()' at line 1
```

There is a reason why I need all in one line, I'm trying to execute this command with PHP code and show respond with javascript in front.
I'm actually working on auto-installation for production for laravel and vue, works with Centos 8 now is Ubuntu time.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using backticks for strings?

Comment: There's no need to do all that in one line; just put it in a `.sh` file and run that from PHP.